# How to enumerate only on \alph level in an enumerate environment, but on \arabic between environments?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to create an enumeration in LaTeX where the first enumeration outputs the following:

(1a) This is an example
(1b) Another example

But the next enumerate which is in my latex doc outputs the following:

(2a) This is an example
(2b) Another example

So I want to only update the alpha inside the enumeration (and keep the integer the same) but I want to update the integer between different enumerations, if that makes sense.

Is this possible in any way? Preferably something automatically, I've tried by using square brackets with every \item separately and that works, but it is a lot to change when I remove an enumerate section for example.

Thanks!

Comment: Please make a [mre] that shows us which documentclass etc. you use

Comment: My document class is \article. I don't have anything else yet, I just want to know if this is at all possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On possibility with the `enumerate` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcounter{foo}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\addtocounter{foo}{1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[({\thefoo}a)]
\item one
\item two
\end{enumerate}


text


\begin{enumerate}[({\thefoo}a)]
\item one
\item two
\end{enumerate}

text

\begin{enumerate}[({\thefoo}a)]
\item one
\item two
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]